# Store user's email on different page when he/she clicks a button

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to store the email of a user when he/she clicks on a (download) button, on a certain page.

This is the code from the button itself:

```
<div class="my_music_download_2" id="try">
  <a class="fas fa-file-download fa-3x" href="<%= my_music.download %>" download></a>

<script> 
document.getElementById("try").addEventListener("click", function(){ 

}); 
</script> 


</div>
```

I don't now what I have to type in the function.

I used devise for my authentication.

My github page: github.com/Maartensdb/steven-de-baecke/tree/fixes

Answer (score 0):

You could store the user's email address in a session and receive it on different pages.

```
// Store
sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: How do I get the email from the user that clicks on it? Since the email is always different.

Comment: you can use an input box in order to collect the user's email. When the user has inserted a valid email address you can activate the download button and store their email address inside the session when they click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your link is inside a loop like:

```
 <% MyMusic.each.do |my_music| %>
```

You can set the view:

```
<%= link_to download_path(my_music_id: my_music.id), remote: true do %>
Download
<% end %>
```

And controller:

```
def download
  @my_music = MyMusic.find(params[my_music_id])
  @my_music.update_attributes(email: current_user.email) 
  send_data @my_music.download.read, filename: @my_music.download
end
```

But this stores for each my_music the last user who downloaded it. If you wanted to store who downloaded what you need to create a join table like users_downloads with columns user_id and my_music_id, then set proper associations.

Comment: I don't think I can use a link_to tag since the button doesn't redirect you to another page but actually downloads something. Thats why there is a download in the back of the a tag     <a class="fas fa-file-download fa-3x" href="<%= my_music.download %>" download></a>  Is there a way so you can download something with an link_to tag instead of an a tag? By the way, what I want is just to see on a diffrent page who downloaded what.